# ftp only shows root directory,

Tags: ftp, file-sharing, filezilla

I am using an old version of FileZilla. It was working properly but since yesterday I am not able to see all the directories and files. The remote window shows the root directory only, I am not able to access other directories. It shows the path `/` and an empty panel with the text "empty directory listing".

In the ftp command prompt it shows like below

```
Response: 230 User logged in.
Command: OPTS UTF8 ON
Response: 200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command: PWD
Response: 257 "/" is current directory.
Command: TYPE I
Response: 200 Type set to I.
Command: PASV
Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (173,0,129,78,236,52).
Command: LIST -a
Response: 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
Response: 226 Transfer complete.
Status: Directory listing successful
```

I turned off the the Windows firewall connection too but I am still facing same issue.

What could be the problem?

Comment: What version of FileZilla are you using? Have you got enough storage space at the destination? Are you using plain FTP or SFTP?

Comment: i am using filezilla 3.10 version, and I have enough space too. And I am using plain FTP

Comment: Can you log into the remote server via a different method to verify the space available?

Comment: yes, I can login through cpanel

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the nonstandard `-a` switch that is sent to the `LIST` command that confuses the server.

It's possible that you have inadvertently enabled *Server > Force showing hidden files* in FileZilla. Try to disable it.

Comment: I disabled Server > Force showing hidden files, but still facing same issue.

Comment: So add a log file for that to the question too. + In FileZilla Debug settings, check *"Show raw directory listing"*.